# Jboss 4.2.1.GA v/s Jboss EAP 7.0.0 Logger

Tags: logging, log4j, jboss-4.2.x, jboss-eap-7

We have migrated an application from Jboss 4.2.1.GA to Jboss EAP 7.0.0. There are many differences we see in clustering,rmi etc. We wanted to know what has changed specify from logging.

As it is a migrational application log4j logger was being used in JB4 is bein used in EAP7 also.

We have created a logger tag XYZ_TRAIL and we use it only for debugging logging only.

In JB4 we have

```
<root>
<priority value="DEBUG"/>
<appender-ref ref="SERVER"/>
</root>
```

And we never get the XYZ_TRAIL logging it not being shown. Although we have not explicitly set XYZ_TRAIL category.
Whereas in EAP7 we have

```
<root-logger>
<level name="DEBUG"/>
<handlers>
<handler name="SERVER"/>
</handlers>
</root-logger>
```

But by default, we are getting the XYZ_TRAIL getting logged and we need to create a logging category to control the same.

Anyone has faced the same issue or knows about as why this happens differently in EAP7?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the `XYZ_TRAIL` logger to log messages you'd need to add the logger with a level of `OFF`.

In CLI it would look something like:

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=XYZ_TRAIL:add(level=OFF)
```

You could also use the web console as well to add the logger or change it's level.